# How to get sub total amout in current session in my custom module

Tags: magento

How to get Sub Total amount of cart within if condition in magento.
Actually i get refer by one tutorials Below is the link.

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total

```
 if(Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::canApply($address)){

                $TotalsData = $address->getTotals();

                $exist_amount = $quote->getFeeAmount();
                $fee = Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
                $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;
                //$balance = $fee;

                //$this->_setAmount($balance);
                //$this->_setBaseAmount($balance);

                $address->setFeeAmount($balance);
                $address->setBaseFeeAmount($balance);

                $quote->setFeeAmount($balance);

                $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $address->getFeeAmount());
                $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseFeeAmount());              
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Vivek try this

```
$address->getSubtotal();
```

OR

```
 totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals();


     $subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue();
```

Comment: 2nd option is the best one. Try to go for that